# Vim Indentation Configuration

Tags: vim, configuration, indentation, vi

What happens in my vim editor is -->
LOOK AT THE CURSOR...

```
int main() {|
```

After pressing enter..
The cursor always comes at the beginning of the line, it does not indent automatically !!

```
int main() {
|
}
```

OR

```
int main() {
    if () {
|
    }
}
```

What I want is...

```
int main() {
    |
}
```

the cursor to have 2 or 4 white-space indentation !!

**How can I do this ??**

My .vimcr:

```
" when I close tab, remove the buffer
set nohidden

" Highlight things that we find with the search
set hlsearch

" Incremental searching 
set incsearch

set smartcase

" Enable mouse support in console
set mouse=a

" Line numbers PWN!
set number 

set shiftwidth=3
set softtabstop=3

set smarttab

set autoindent
set smartindent 
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

inoremap {<cr> {<CR><CR>}<Esc>-cc
```

Comment: Add the ouput of `:filetype` and `:set filetype?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I sorted out the solution myself, just remove smartindent !!!